# JavaScript and HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm working on a Django project and I'm trying to add buttons that onclick direct you to another page, on a table that is built from a model.

Here is the HTML for the table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzddu.png

And here is the JS function:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLas9.png

On the site this looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAZ76.png

The first button where the ID is 1 when clicked takes me to the right page.
The second button though is not doing anything check clicked.
What I'm trying to achieve is every time an application object is created and the table is updated I want the to be able to click the button and go to a page with a url like this: /review/id wit the id being the same as the one on the table.

Comment: I don't see the code

Comment: Please avoid [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) thanks.

Comment: Put a <a> tag with the same style as your button and put the url in the href

Comment: @OscarGonzalez how exactly would that work? I've tried but I get some funny results

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry about this, It is my 1st post I should be using the code entry to share my code right?

Comment: Correct! Code as text is the way to go. It makes it a lot easier for others to run the code and ultimate answer your question accurately.

Comment: @OscarGonzalez Ok I think I got it, I added the <a> tag as you said and then the button within it with href="/review/{{ app.id }}"

Comment: @ninisau79 sorry I didn't read this you have to put your href something like this: `href="{% url 'YOUR_URL_NAME' app.id %}"`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have multiple buttons with the same ID's, ID's should be unique. Try giving the buttons a class, and linking the onclick to these classes.

```
<button id="review{{ app.id }}" class="btn btn-primary reviewBtn" data-id={{app.id}}">Review</button>
```

```
var reviews = document.getElementsByClassName("reviewBtn");
var redirect = function() {
    @TODO
};


for (var i = 0; i < reviews.length; i++) {
    reviews[i].addEventListener('click', redirect, false);
}
```

see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jytq6gxc/)

Comment: still the same id

Comment: I tried this solution but It did not work, neither of the two buttons where redirecting when clicked

Comment: @ninisau79 my bad, I updated my post with a working demo